# Using Xamarin Studio to authenticate to Azure AD and connect to Microsoft Graph for iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, office365, microsoft-graph-api

There are lots of outdated examples of code, but does anyone have an example of a new project authenticating to Azure AD, after the app is registered in Azure, for iOS in Xamarin Studio (Mac)?

Most examples are for Visual Studio, or Xamarin Studio.Android.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would a Xamarin Forms sample that uses [MSAL](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ad/2016/03/31/microsoft-identity-at-build-2016/) for authentication and the .NET [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/) work for you? You can open a Forms sample in both Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio on a Mac. We should be able to publish that sample very soon. We also have these two Xamarin Forms samples:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft Graph SDK sample has just been published: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/xamarin-csharp-connect-sample